# I am getting wrong result in python when I trying to compare the two strings in python

Tags: python, string, comparison

Why I am getting wrong result when I compare the two strings .

```
if password==en_pass:
            log.info("##### client credentials are OK ####")
else:
     print "credentials are wrong "
```

i am getting the result which is in else block

Here is the my log message:

```
got the password :bmF2ZWVu  , encoded password :bmF2ZWVu
```

where encoded password is from `base64` , that is i got that by using encodestring method in `base 64` module.

Comment: Can you enclose the password is quotes and check for spaces? Looking at that there is no reason it shouldn't work.

Comment: you should try putting quotes around the passwords, and you should give how you print the log message. And also check the types of password and en_pass.

Comment: you can use repr("your string"), to print out the exact content!

Comment: Looks like there are spaces in the password. Print their repr() instead of their string representation (use `%r` instead of `%s`).

Comment: Why are you comparing a plain text password against an `encrypted` password, shouldn't it be `if encrypt(password) == en_pass`?

Comment: Thank you for your comments , yes there is a new line   character
 I used the strip and repr then i got that , then it's valid

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it seems that password is not `'bmF2ZWVu'`, but contains trailing spaces, like `'bmF2ZWVu   '`. Try `if password.strip()==en_pass.strip()`

Comment: do you mean it's of other data type ?

Comment: @usernaveen he means that there are some space characters after the password.

Comment: @Ashwini  : Oh thank god ,  now it's  valid.....
Thank you , i got that there is a newline  character